# select data from subquery mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

```
select t1.table1 from table1 as t1
where t1.column1 
in 
(
    select t2.column2 from table2 as t2 
    join 
    table3 as t3  on t2.column1=t3.column1 
    where t3.columnx=5
);
```

Above is the mysql query i am firing. Wanted some data from the subquery tables also.

For example say columnxy from table t2.

query that fails

```
select t1.table1,t2.columnxy from table1 as t1
where t1.column1 
in 
(
    select t2.column2 from table2 as t2 
    join 
    table3 as t3  on t2.column1=t3.column1 
    where t3.columnx=5
);
```

If i add them with select of the outer query gives error "unknown column" which does make sense.

Is the right way or should rewrite query with joins?

Comment: Show the query that failed - we can advise better

Comment: added the query that is failing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite the query with joins:

```
SELECT t1.table1, t.columnxy
FROM   table1 AS t1 JOIN (
  SELECT t2.column2, t2.columnxy
  FROM   table2 AS t2 JOIN table3 AS t3 USING (column1)
  WHERE  t3.columnx = 5
) t ON t1.column1 = t.column2
```

Or:

```
SELECT t1.table1, t2.columnxy
FROM   table1 AS t1
  JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.column1 = t2.column2
  JOIN table3 AS t3 ON t2.column1 = t3.column1
WHERE  t3.columnx = 5
```

Answer (score 2):

The t2 is not available at that point. You should use a join for this. Using t1.column1=t2.column2 should do it.

Comment: right, that's the issue i am having, searching for the workaround.